# Clear forms on successful submission

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have a registration form where the form will:

1. Clear form on a successful submission
2. Don't clear form on an error submission (in my case, unmatched passwords)

Here's my code:

```
<input name="uname" type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST["uname"])) { echo $_POST["uname"]; } else { echo ''; };  ?>" required>
```

This code works for the **don't clear form on an error submission**. Although the submission is successful, the form still keeps the data after the form submission. Since, i'm using this code, obviously the reset button won't work too. Therefore, how do i clear it after **successful submission**?

Anyway here's the code for form validation:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

              try {

                if ($_POST["pwd"] == $_POST["cpwd"]) {//matched passwords

                  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_customers(fld_customer_fname,
                    fld_customer_lname, fld_customer_gender, fld_customer_phone, fld_customer_email, fld_customer_username, fld_customer_password) VALUES(:fname, :lname,
                    :gender, :phone, :email, :uname, :pwd)");

                  $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
                  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
                  $gender =  $_POST['gender'];
                  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                  $email = $_POST['email'];
                  $uname = $_POST['uname'];
                  $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

                  $stmt->execute();
                  ?>
                  <br>
                  <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <strong>Success!</strong> Account created.
                  </div>
                  <?php
                }
                else{//unmatched passwords
                  ?>
                  <br>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <strong>Error!</strong> Passwords do not match.
                  </div>
                  <?php
                }
              }
```

Comment: Would you be apposed to doing it with javascript? or does it need to be with PHP?

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda it would be wonderful to have both? but i prefer it to be in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you render your form fields after you check if it was success or not. If I am right, set in success also some `$success` variable to true

`$success = true;`

when you have success or to false where not. And then in rendering input just do:

```
<input name="uname" type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST["uname"]) && !$success) { echo $_POST["uname"]; } ?>" required>
```

ps: you do not need `else { echo ''; };` ;)

Comment: `if ($_POST["pwd"] == $_POST["cpwd"]) {...... $success = true;} else {..... $success = false;}`

Comment: ah okay i kinda set it like this `$success = "true";` my bad. and it works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript and JQuery, it's possible with commands like this:

```
$(".myform")[0].reset();
```

With PHP, you could also just redirect after the form submits to the same page (reload):

```
header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Another way to do this in PHP is through a storing a variable like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $post_val=$_POST;
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then unset `$post_val` after submit:

```
unset($post_val);
```

Just Show your Values with `$post_val`

```
<input type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo $_post_val["name"]?>"/>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_post_val["email"]?>"/>   
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_post_val["phone"]?>"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: however if i use the second option which is to redirect the page, the form won't display the **success message** since it refreshes the page :/

Comment: I see, glad that I could help in anyway though!